# While upgrading Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04, it got struct. Only prompt is showing

Tags: upgrade, internet

While upgrading Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04, it got struct. Only prompt is showing.I am not able to login.
Please help me to come out of this.

Comment: Can you clarify (by editing your question) what you mean by "it got struct"? In particular, was there a power failure? Did the upgrade process fail with an error message? Did it appear to succeed, but now only boots you to a non-graphical command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

Try logging on. When you enter your password, you won't see anything happening--that's fine.

When you get a prompt (which looks like `$ _`), run these commands, one after the other. Some may take a while to complete.

```
script
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
exit
sudo reboot
```

That might fix the problem. If it doesn't, log back in and run these commands:

```
script -a
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
exit
sudo reboot
```

If that doesn't work either, the reason might be that you don't have an Internet connection. If so, please comment here to indicate that and I'll try to figure out some easy way for you to add the text from the terminal to your question. (But it's even better if you can plug the machine into a wired Ethernet network connection, which will probably work.)

If the problem isn't with connecting to the Internet, then run these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install pastebinit
pastebinit ~/typescript
```

You'll get a URL from that. Copy it down. Navigate to it in a web browser on a machine with a working graphical interface (whatever you're using to access AskUbuntu). Either

- copy all the text from it into your question (and give it code highlighting with the `<$>` tool so it appears correctly), or,
- if it's really really long (more than a few hundred lines), just add the Pastebin link to your question.

Then we can see what happened. (You may be asked to submit log files using a similar method...but hopefully the above technique will just fix the problem, and if it doesn't, hopefully the information gleaned from it will be enough to figure out how to fix it.)

**If the problem does appear to be fixed, then you can figure out what version of Ubuntu you're running now by checking the output of `lsb_release -a`.**